# I want to add remote branch of my local repo?

Tags: linux, git

I want to put my local git project in production server (Linux multi hosting account of go-daddy).
 Is it possible to add my production server as my remote branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, having logged in via SSH:

```
$ mkdir mywebsite.git
$ cd mywebsite.git
$ git init --bare
```

on local git repo

```
$ git remote add production git@myserver.com:mywebsite.git
$ git push production +master:refs/heads/master
```

I got my solution,but thnx all of you !! :-)

Comment: +1, but I would still recommend a git push -u production master for the first push, as I mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new remote:

```
git remote add prod /url/to/empty/bare/repo
```

And then push your master branch to it:

```
git push -u prod master
```

But that supposes you initiated a bare repo on that production server first.

Answer (score 0):

If git is installed on your server and you have cloned a copy of the repository there, you can add it as a remote using `git remote`.

```
git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--[no-]tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>
```

So:

```
git remote add production URL
```

You'd need to push from local and pull on the remote though. So you'd still have to SSH into your server to deploy.

If your end goal is simplified deployment you may wish to look into tools like Jenkins, which you can run locally and can be configured to connect to your server and deploy after running tests, etc.

That might be your best option if your hosting provider won't let you install Git.

Answer (score -1):

Yes possible. You need the following command:

git remote add (remote-name)

Comment: usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>